# How to get son and dad to stop fighting?

Tags: dogs, behavior, safety, multi-pet-families

I have 3 dogs. 2 blue nose pitts (both male) and a mini dotson (female). The mini was here first and then we got the oldest pitt. They are currently 3/4 years old and we've had them since 9 months.

The pitt had a history of being abused but has always been a huge puppy to us... great with kids and other dogs. Our other pitt is his son he is 1 going on 2 now and was the runt of the litter so he wasn't treated the best by his mother but we took him in at 5 weeks old. He was born with a weak immune system so he got very sick and we thought we were going to lose him but after a couple Shots and a lot of love from us and his dad who was excited to have him he came back to health.

After that everything was fine they played and loved each other his dad loved having him around and we even brought one of the other pups to see them. The son was always a little aggressive but not to the point wherr they would fight or we would be concerned and he also loves kids.

In june we had a house fire started in the garage but didn't spread throughout the house it was just scary and it triggered something in them. The oldest pitt almost didn't make it because he was trying to make sure everyone was out the house but luckly he got out without injury.

For the first few weeks that we had to stay at a hotel and leave the dogs at home or with a friend they were fine no fighting and were just happy to see us when We'd come home during the day. But one day a fight started we stopped it and separated them cleaning them up and then bringing them back after they calmed down and it was okay they got along again but after we started coming home and sleeping here again the fights happened more frequently and got so bad it was hard to stop them.

Now we have them in cages by each other but sometimes a growl and tension still happens. We have to take them walking and out side at different times because we don't want them to fight. What can we do to get them to get along? They miss each other and look for each other when one is missing but they still try to fight sometimes. We don't want to give either away and neither of them have been neutered.

Comment: The first thing you can do is neuter them, it will help in reducing this behaviour

Comment: I totally agree with @YvetteColomb about getting them both neutered. And although the fire must have been VERY traumatic for both you and your dogs, is there a chance all this change happened as your pup was reaching puberty and releasing different hormones? Your oldest may think he his a threat to him as leader of the pack or as alpha male, and altering them may be one of your best solutions. Neutering also reduces the chance of many other health problems in their future. The trauma may also be playing a role, and I do not wish to discredit THAT as being a part of the issue.